# Is there any way I can get this input colorized in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The theme I'm using is Eva Dark. Here's the problem

the input circled in red shows the input function white, whereas it's supposed to be light blue like the int there.

[image]

Comment: what is the TextMate class of `int` and `input`

Comment: I actually don't know

Comment: it helps if you show the link to the marketplace of this Theme or the full name of the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textmate scopes for `input` are

```
textmate scopes
   support.function.builtin.python
   meta.function-call.python
   meta.function-call.arguments.python
   meta.function-call.python
   source.python
```

[One of the **meta.function-call.python** scopes is an error and is part of the python language server]

in the theme the color for `input` is determined by

```
foreground  meta.function-call.arguments.python support.function.builtin.python
{ "foreground": "#B0B7C3", "fontStyle": "" }
```

---

The textmate scopes for `print` are

```
textmate scopes
   support.function.builtin.python
   meta.function-call.python
   source.python
```

in the theme the color for `print` is determined by

```
foreground  meta.function-call.python support.function.builtin.python
{ "foreground": "#56B7C3", "fontStyle": "" }
```

---

Because of the extra specification of the scope you have to name it the override in `settings.json`

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Eva Dark]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        { "scope":"meta.function-call.arguments.python support.function.builtin.python",
          "settings": {"foreground": "#56B7C3"}
        },
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn to **Manage** -> **Color Theme**, you can try **Monokai**:
[image]

Comment: why you want me to try monokai? Eva Dark is my favourite theme

Comment: I don't care if it's your favourite theme. But since you're using it and want to customize color, have you ever thought of editing its [Eva Dark.json](https://github.com/fisheva/Eva-Theme/blob/master/themes/Eva-Dark.json) to achieve goals?

Comment: @Rabab Rahman. I'm trying to edit the existed style settings or even add new configurations. If it works, i'll let you know.

Comment: thnx for ur help